# regex needed to strip out domain name

Tags: regex

I need a regexp to strip out just the domain name part of a url. So for example if i had the following url:

http://www.website-2000.com

the bit I'd want the regex to match would be 'website-2000'

If you could also explain which each part of the regex does to help me understand it that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Domain name validation with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one should work. There might be some faults with it, but none that I can think of right now. If anyone want to improve on it, feel free to do so.

```
/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9\-]+)(?:\.[a-z\.]+[\/]?).*/i

http:\/\/            matches the "http://" part
(?:www\.)?           is a non-capturing group that matches zero or one "www."
([a-z0-9\-]+)        is a capturing group that matches character ranges a-z, 0-9
                     in addition to the hyphen. This is what you wanted to extract.
(?:\.[a-z\.]+[\/]?)  is a non-capturing group that matches the TLD part (i.e. ".com",
                     ".co.uk", etc) in addition to zero or one "/"
.*                   matches the rest of the url
```

http://rubular.com/r/ROz13NSWBQ

Comment: The `.*` in the end is wrong. Replace it with `[^ ]*`. It also captures characters after the domain name. For eg, in `http://www.website-2000.com jerry hates tom`, `jerry hates tom` will also be captured by regex. Not in scope of question, but will help for a broader usage of your regex.

Answer (score 4):

Let me introduce you this wonderful tool txt2re: [regular expression generator](http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=http://www.website-2000.com&4&6)

Here you can experiment with regex and generate code in many languages.

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 1):

```
r/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/?#]+//
```

This worked for me.

It will match any scheme or protocol  and then after the :// matches any character that's not a / ? or #.  These three characters, when they first occur in a URL, signal the end of the domain so that's were I end the match.

Comment: For me to. In JavaScript it's look as  `url.replace(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/?#]+/, '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
http://wwww.([^/]+)
```

<s>No need to use regexp, use the urlparse module</s>

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> '.'.join(urlparse("http://www.website-2000.com").netloc.split('.')[-2:])
'website-2000.com'
```

Comment: sorry I need to do it with regex

Comment: Oh, stupid me, didn't notice that this wasn't a python question

Comment: Well, that's certainly a bit simpler than my behemoth.

Comment: The expression: `http://wwww.([^/]+)` does not work for: `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com?qvar=qval`.

Comment: because there are 4 Ws in this regex

Answer (score -1):

This one allows you not to have to worry about any of the http/https/ftp etc... in front and also captures all your subdomains too.

```
(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9\-.]+)(?:\.[a-z\.]+[\/]?).*/i
```

The only times it fails that I've found are:
- If a . precedes the domain/subdomain without any text before it, the . is included in the regex capture.
- Emails with . in them will not work. (fix this by checking passed domain first for the @ symbol before running through regex)
- Whitespace in the middle of the domain/subdomain