# What is a regular expression which will match a valid domain name without a subdomain?

Tags: regex, validation, domain-name

I need to validate a domain name:

**google.com**

**stackoverflow.com**

So a domain in its rawest form - not even a subdomain like www.

1. Characters should only be **a-z** | **A-Z** | **0-9** and **period**(.) and **dash**(-)
2. The domain name part should not start or end with dash (-) *(e.g. -google-.com)*
3. The domain name part should be between 1 and 63 characters long
4. <strike>The extension (TLD) can be anything under #1 rules for now, I may validate them against a list later, it should be 1 or more characters though</strike>

<strike>Edit: TLD is apparently 2-6 chars as it stands</strike>

**no. 4 revised:** TLD should actually be labelled "subdomain" as it should include things like .co.uk -- I would imagine the only validation possible (apart from checking against a list) would be 'after the first dot there should be one or more characters under rules #1

Thanks very much, believe me I did try!

Comment: It would be wise to consider URI validation rather than domain name validation. Look at IETF RFC3986.

Comment: May be not helpful at all. 
When it comes to google.co.uk, and some Japanese domains, I'm sure you will have to think twice before using regex for that. My personal thought is that regex is not enough to validate a domain to a real-life domain. 
FYI, here is an almost complete list of tlds and country code second level domains list: http://static.ayesh.me/misc/SO/tlds.txt

Comment: See my answer to the related question about [hostname validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address/3824105#3824105).

Comment: Often forgotten: For full qualified domain names you should match a period after the tld.

Comment: Please note that a lot of new TLDs are coming up. And some are quite long, for example xn--vermgensberatung-pwb is a valid TLD and is 24 characters long :p

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491074/112731

Comment: it's been 4 years, now the count is up to 89,000

Comment: Some of these answers are pretty good, but there's also another [good answer on this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026957/how-to-validate-a-domain-name-using-regex-php/16491074#16491074) that's worth a look.

Comment: Congratulations on asking the 10,000th regex question!

Comment: .co.uk is not a TLD and I would bitchslap anyone who claims otherwise. Stop confusing people by repeating the same mistake. The TLD is .uk and co.uk is a SLD which would make it a subdomain of .uk

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Well, it's <strike>pretty straightforward</strike> a little sneakier than it looks (see comments), given your specific requirements:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

But note this will reject a lot of valid domains.

Comment: Nice thanks this one seems to be working. What kind of domains won't pass validation do you know?

Comment: @infensus: Well, anything with leading URL components attached (e.g. `http://example.com` or `user:pass@example.com`), though to be fair that's not actually part of the domain. Longer domains wouldn't be matched. But most importantly, domains containing sub-domains won't be matched.

Comment: .museum is longer than 4 characters. And OP says he only has one rule for tlds.

Comment: Thats alright I already removed the http:// type protocol and all subdomains from the string, though I haven't considered user:pass@example.com - will remove anything before an @. This is for http domain name lookup so I don't need any of that stuff!

Comment: @infensus - While this regex is correct given your specs, your specs are wrong. `g.co` is a valid domain name but `g` is only one character.

Comment: @sch thanks I read that wrong somewhere - Good to know! Now I am reading mixed things like it can be as long as you want, that most domain providers limit to 255, and still more that say the toplevel part can be a max of 63

Comment: This should match all cases I think: ^([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-]{1,61})?[a-z0-9]{1})?(\.[a-z0-9](([a-z0-9-]{1,61})?[a-z0-9]{1})?)?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$

Comment: @infensus: this regexp will reject bbc.co.uk: the 'subdomain' concept is totally wrong as you use it, since TLD means Top Domain Name - 'com' is a domain, 'google.com' a 'subdomain'

Comment: x.com would not pass here

Comment: @Neil: You're right. The original question asked for 3-63 characters (see edit 3). It can be changed to support one-character domains fairly easily: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`. But this still rejects tons of valid stuff...

Comment: @Cameron what valid domains does

Comment: Use ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+){1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ for allowing sub domains and domain name starts www. I modified this to work with knockout validation.

Comment: @Nish That does not "allow" sub domains, it requires them.

Comment: please elaborate more on what you mean by `But note this will reject a lot of valid domains.`

Comment: This doesn't have an exclusion for double-dashes in the domain name, which I believe aren't allowed in the RFC, outside of punycode.

Comment: this doesn't even support `.co.uk` tld either.

Comment: localhost doesn't match but it's a valid domain name.

Comment: @mastazi: Yes, as I wrote in the answer "But note this will reject a lot of valid domains." This was an answer to a very specific question, that unfortunately gets undue search traffic thanks to the generic title, but is a terrible way to validate domains.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: Yes. Read the comment just before yours (and the question title) ;-)

Comment: @Cameron , sorry about that. I was just desperate at that moment for a solution and didnt read any comments. My bad sir.

Comment: what about the final upper limit of 253 characters?

Comment: This doesnt seem to match the full domain when there is a hypen e.g. https://sub.some-site.com/ only matches "sub.some"

Answer (score 140):

I know that this is a bit of an old post, but all of the regular expressions here are missing one very important component: the support for IDN domain names.

[IDN domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) start with xn--. They enable extended UTF-8 characters in domain names. For example, did you know "♡.com" is a valid domain name? Yeah, "love heart dot com"! To validate the domain name, you need to let http://xn--c6h.com/ pass the validation.

Note, to use this regex, you will need to convert the domain to lower case, and also use an IDN library to ensure you encode domain names to ACE (also known as "ASCII Compatible Encoding"). One good library is GNU-Libidn.

idn(1) is the command line interface to the internationalized domain name library. The following example converts the host name in UTF-8 into ACE encoding. The resulting URL https://nic.xn--flw351e/ can then be used as ACE-encoded equivalent of [https://nic.谷歌/](https://nic.xn--flw351e/).

```
  $ idn --quiet -a nic.谷歌
  nic.xn--flw351e
```

This magic regular expression should cover *most* domains (although, I am sure there are many valid edge cases that I have missed):

```
^((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,1}\.(xn--)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$
```

When choosing a domain validation regex, you should see if the domain matches the following:

1. xn--stackoverflow.com
2. stackoverflow.xn--com
3. stackoverflow.co.uk

If these three domains do not pass, your regular expression may be not allowing legitimate domains!

Check out [The Internationalized Domain Names Support page from Oracle's International Language Environment Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmkx.html) for more information.

Feel free to try out the regex here: http://www.regexr.com/3abjr

**ICANN** keeps [a list of tlds that have been delegated](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings) which can be used to see some examples of IDN domains.

---

Edit:

```
 ^(((?!-))(xn--|_)?[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn--)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,60}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$
```

This regular expression will stop domains that have '-' at the end of a hostname as being marked as being valid. Additionally, it allows unlimited subdomains.

Comment: Note that this will only support max one subdomain, anything more than that will result in false. It's not something that you're libel to run into unless using it for internal sites, etc... A quick attempt to allow it to support more subdomains: `/^((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,}\.?((xn--)?([a-z0-9\-.]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30})\.?[a-z]{2,})$/i`

Comment: But lonely tld's are not working :( For example `to.` ( http://to./ ) is valid url with content.

Comment: @iiic, yes, but `to.` is not a fully qualified domain name. If you want to allow top level domains, then you should use something like `^(((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,1}\.)?(x--)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})\.?$`, but be warned, you will let through people putting in domains like `test` or `na`, too!

Comment: It accepts `invali.d` as a valid domain name while `invali.d.co.uk` is invalid.

Comment: @PawelKrakowiak `^(((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn--)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$` (Note that 'invali.d.co.uk' is not really a domain name in the traditional sense. A domain name usually only has a first or second-level hierarchy from the TLD/2LD)

Comment: This regular expression is not correct. For example, it matches domain names starting with `-`.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov the regular expression starts with `^(((?!-))`, which explicitly states that it should not start with an `-`. Do you have an example of a domain where it does match a domain starting with `-`? My quick tests show that the regular expression fails with domains starting with `-`.

Comment: @timgws In python:


    `In [2]: d = re.compile('^(((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn--)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$')`
    
    `In [3]: d.match('-google')`
    `Out[3]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7fb716eff480>`


It works if I move `(?!-)` before the `^`:


    `(?!-)^((xn--)?[-a-z0-9_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)*(xn--)?([a-z0-9-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$`


(also cleaned useless fluff like `{1,1}`)

Comment: @EugeneMorozov `{1,1}` is not useless fluff. It means that it must match (and only match) one character between `a-z` or `0-9`. This is to stop having `-` at the end of domain names (which is invalid).

Comment: @timgws But any character or character class or group matches exactly one time even without `{1,1}`. It's like writing `h{1,1}i{1,1}` instead of `hi` - just makes reading harder.

Comment: this regex accepts `1-800-321-43` as a domain name. Is it valid domain name (i'm seriously asking...)?

Comment: @FilipBartuzi it shouldn't match raw TLD's. I just checked and it is. Example: *.com* is a TLD, with `com.` being the correct root for the domain. 1-800-321-43.com is a valid domain, and I guess there is no technical reason why `.1-800-321-43` could not be a valid TLD

Comment: This regex does not match domains with latin extension - eg. `rębąśęd.pl`

Comment: @FilipBartuzi this is mentioned: `use an IDN library to ensure you encode domain names to ACE`. They are not actually valid domain names (DNS only supports a subset of letters and numbers, ACE/IDN is what makes these work).

Comment: @TimGroeneveld, your regex considers a normal string valid: iE 'ihave-no-dot'. `^(((?!\-))(xn\-\-)?[a-z0-9\-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn\-\-)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9\-]{1,30})\.[a-z]{2,}$` fixes this - it closes the last `)` bracket before the dot `\.` and the TLD `[a-z]{2,}`

Comment: "-" it is the valid domain according to your regex

Comment: It should be noted that `xn--stackoverflow.com` is not a valid name as 'stackoverflow' can not be converted from Punycode. That however is beyond what a regex can do. As a general remark, `xn--[a-z0-9]+` labels would be IDN-only whereas `xn--[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+` indicate a mix of ASCII- and non-ASCII characters

Comment: @Marcus noted, it's more just that if xn--stackoverflow.com does not pass the validation, you can be almost guaranteed that the regex will not support IDNs

Comment: `domain.com.com.com.com.com.com.com.com.com` is valid 

Comment: Note that this regex is not safe on user-controller input since it causes catastrophic backtracking i.e. exponential time increase leading to basically infinite match time on certain inputs, like `xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a.xn--a!`. The way to avoid this is to remove the `(xn--)?` parts. These are entirely unnecessary since `[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}` already matches them which leads to the problematic ambiguity.

Comment: There is just simply too many problems with this regex:
- many comments above, especially the prev.
- as already said it allows leading `-`. The simple negative lookbehind being totally ineffective and wrong, as what you wrote is LOOKAHEAD, and the next char. set `[a-z0-9\-_]` totally allows starting with `-`...
- also char. sets with `-` should ALWAYS have it as the LAST to help reading (and then you don't have to, or as a matter of taste, shouldn't escape them

Comment: What is this (directly before the TLD part) `([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9\-]{1,30})`?
The same char set but either 1-61 length, or 1-30 length?
Simply just `[a-z0-9-]{1,61}` is the same, or `[[:alnum:]-]{1,61}` if posix char classes allowed.

Comment: @benediktwerner understand - the answer that I originally gave has been edited (by another SO user), hence these mistakes. Feel free to edit the answer again to fix the regex.

Comment: @Sandra `com.com` is a valid (and registered!) domain. Thus any subdomain of it is also valid. This Q&A is about validating the **syntax** of a domain, not whether it is fit for a particular purpose, nor whether someone has entered the "right" domain.

Comment: only works in JavaScript with the `u` flag in order support extended unicode plane

Answer (score 56):

My RegEx is next:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}\.([a-zA-Z]{1,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$`

it's ok for **i.oh1.me** and for **wow.british-library.uk**

**UPD**

Here is updated rule

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

https://www.debuggex.com/r/y4Xe_hDVO11bv1DV

now it check for `-` or `_` in the start or end of domain label.

Comment: Looks pretty good, but the `{2,6}` criteria will need to be updated for the new TLD. Probably `{2,}`.

Comment: @jwatts1980 is there an examples of such zones? or you mean for possible future zones?

Comment: Here is an article discussing the upcoming changes with examples and links to related resources: http://www.zdnet.com/ready-or-not-here-come-the-new-internet-top-level-domain-names-7000025744/

Comment: @behz4d can you please provide an example?

Comment: @behz4d it does't accepts for me nor in that regexp service (debuggex) nor in my html/js input fields

Comment: Why ([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}) and not ([a-zA-Z]{2})?

Comment: fails if you provide an ip

Comment: @Anton yeah, you are right, for code clean uping, it's better to use [a-zA-Z]{2} =)

Comment: @MarekR, yep, as ip's is out of scope here

Comment: Unfortunately, this misses a lot of official TLD names, like .audio etc.  Here is the list of official TLD's.  http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: the last part with the two alternatives is also wrong: there exists ccTLDs (two letters) that accept IDNA sublabels. There also exists now TLDs labels already using  IDNA labels.
You should not special case the last label which is not different from others (and now has many extensions added with variable lengths, jsut like all other labels in subdomains.
note the IDNA labels may also appear Punycoded (in which case there will be "--" a segment in the label, the only case where "--" is allowed in labels..
Finally the underscore is invalid everywhere in all labels.

Comment: Couldn't the 'non-TLD' portion of this updated regex be simplified to `([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])`;  Thus the whole regex could be simplified to `^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$`

Comment: @DanielDai it should not, as it designed to work with top level domain names and not sub-domains

Comment: `www.japantimes.co.jp` doesn't match but `www.google.com` does?

Comment: @RoyalTS validate domains, but not subdomains. You have to strip out `www` before validating

Comment: @verdy_p Are you sure about the underscore or are you possibly mixing it up with possible hostname characters?

Comment: This doesn't support `foo.bar.co.uk`.

Answer (score 46):

**My bet:**

```
^(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$
```

**Explained:**

Domain name is built from segments. Here is one segment (except final):

```
[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?
```

It can have 1-63 characters, does not start or end with '-'.

Now append '.' to it and repeat at least one time:

```
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+
```

Then attach final segment, which is 2-63 characters long:

```
[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]
```

**Test it here:** http://regexr.com/3au3g

Comment: @GaneshBabu What do you mean by exact matches?

Comment: All other answers didn't worked for me but this one did.

Comment: I had a similar requirement where I want to avoid semicolon and comma at the end I tried a lot but no success below is the Regex I am using const regexDomain = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]/g; Well it validates if I use , and ; in between but fails at the end to vliadate.

Comment: I found several domains that should be valid but are invalid with your regex. For example редбулл.москва is a valid domain or also редбулл.рф and 红色的公牛.中国

Comment: @pubkey, you need to convert those domain names to [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). Actual name for редбулл.москва is xn--90afc0aazy.xn--80adxhks And my regex does match it.

Comment: This really is the best regex that doens't go off the rails. It handles single character labels, it can handle IDN domains (converted to punycode), and has no absurd length requirement on TLD. I think you would be hardpressed to find a domain which it does not match. The only thing it doens't enforce is the max length of a domain (253 characters) However a simple length check could easily be used with the regex.

Comment: As as I know, *I think* domains shouldn't start with numbers nor end with them (per rfc1035 on [page 8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#page-8)). Note however that I could be wrong on ending on a digit; that might be allowed, but I've never seen it. My modified version of this (simply removes `0-9` in the first and last sequences): `^(?:[a-z](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z]$`

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt get php's FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN in a filter_var to work but your regex worked ! Thanks. Note - FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL works fine in my code. Unsure why i couldnt get FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN``` to work. Popped your regex into a ```preg_match``` and it worked immediately. I just removed 0-9 from the last part though.

Comment: A fully-qualified domain name can end with a final dot. http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html

Comment: `domain.com.com.com.com.com.com.com.com.com` is valid 

Comment: @Sandra : `com.com` is an existing domain and any number of subdomains is allowed, so this is relatively normal that it validates it.

Comment: Plus 1, https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/02/24/coder-on-the-verge-of-extinction/ - Sidenote, notice how easy it is to fool SO's regex check on comments that start with +1 :D

Answer (score 21):

#### This answer is for domain names (including service RRs), not host names (like an email hostname).

```
^(?=.{1,253}\.?$)(?:(?!-|[^.]+_)[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,63}(?<!-)(?:\.|$)){2,}$
```

It is basically [mkyong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717506/436063) and additionally:

- Max length of 255 octets including length prefixes and null root.
- Allow trailing '.' for explicit dns root.
- Allow leading '_' for service domain RRs, (bugs: doesn't enforce 15 char max for _ labels, nor does it require at least one domain above service RRs)
- Matches all possible TLDs.
- Doesn't capture subdomain labels.

#### By Parts

Lookahead, limit max length between ^$ to 253 characters with optional trailing literal '.'

```
(?=.{1,253}\.?$)
```

Lookahead, next character is not a '-' and no '_' follows any characters before the next '.'. That is to say, enforce that the first character of a label isn't a '-' and only the first character may be a '_'.

```
(?!-|[^.]+_)
```

Between 1 and 63 of the allowed characters per label.

```
[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,63}
```

Lookbehind, previous character not '-'. That is to say, enforce that the last character of a label isn't a '-'.

```
(?<!-)
```

Force a '.' at the end of every label except the last, where it is optional.

```
(?:\.|$)
```

Mostly combined from above, this requires at least two domain levels, which is not quite correct, but usually a reasonable assumption. Change from {2,} to + if you want to allow TLDs or unqualified relative subdomains through (eg, localhost, myrouter, to.)

```
(?:(?!-|[^.]+_)[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,63}(?<!-)(?:\.|$)){2,}
```

[Unit tests](https://regex101.com/r/d5Yd6j/1/tests) for this expression.

Comment: Thanks! This is the best regex here. Your thorough explanation and unit test are a bonus.

Comment: What does "RR" mean?

Comment: Resource Record. Usually a text or informational field that tells you how to interact with a service.

Comment: This regex is not correct. For example the domain redbull.移动 is valid but the regex will not match.

Comment: Convert to punycode first, then match. Length limits on the pre-punycode version are really hard to implement.

Answer (score 17):

Just a minor correction - the last part should be up to 6. Hence,

```
^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$
```

The longest TLD is `museum` (6 chars) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: Note: This will not pass the valid (yet rare) domain name www.my---domain.com

Comment: Doesn't cut it with new TLD e.g. `.photography`

Comment: @SamFigueroa You'll just have to modify the length of it

Comment: `.museum` is no longer the longest TLD.

Comment: what about existing .consulting (10 chars)??

Comment: there shouldn't be a check for the TLD it's not different from the subdomains. And basing the regex on currently `available` tlds isn't future proof.

Comment: Suggest last bit be `{2,63}`: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be

Answer (score 15):

Accepted answer not working for me, try this :

> ^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$

Visit this [Unit Test Cases](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/domain-name-regular-expression-example/) for validation.

Comment: no support for new longer TLD names like .audio, .photography, and most of these... http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: @mrbinky3000 Just change the last `{2,6}` to something else and it'll work. Mine: `^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)$`

Comment: @Mygod your regex contains some zero width garbage past the last question mark, so anyone copying it will be unpleasantly surprised

Comment: @MightyPork You're right! Sorry here's a (hopefully) clean version: `^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)$`

Comment: Very nice. Alas, lookbehind expressions are not valid in JavaScript. :/

Comment: So I changed it to `/^(?:(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i`.Slightly less elegant, but does the job.

Comment: I like this one: it's fairly simple and short, well-explained (even if one has to go to another page for the explanation), allows potential future options (if they come up with some xn-- like thing again)... the only thing is the TLD restriction, that should in 2019 definitely be more than 6 in length, and maybe we'll have IDN TLDs some day, so I'd just add a dot to the user's input and remove the TLD matching part (but leave the `$`).

Comment: I changed the last {2,6} to allow a longer TLD (ex. Photography) and this works great for all my use-cases.

Comment: @PhilLho this was the special sauce, thank you 

Answer (score 12):

As already pointed out it's not obvious to tell subdomains in the practical sense (e.g. `.co.uk` domains). [We use](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/57cbbf72f1152214a160f9be8a57e2c4dc868cfd/etc/regex.md) this regex to validate domains which occur in the wild. It covers all practical use cases I know of. New ones are welcome. According to [our guidelines](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/a173a9a5524cbcec480d021e053475b20e3169fc/etc/regex.md) it avoids non-capturing groups and greedy matching.

`^(?!.*?_.*?)(?!(?:[\d\w]+?\.)?\-[\w\d\.\-]*?)(?![\w\d]+?\-\.(?:[\d\w\.\-]+?))(?=[\w\d])(?=[\w\d\.\-]*?\.+[\w\d\.\-]*?)(?![\w\d\.\-]{254})(?!(?:\.?[\w\d\-\.]*?[\w\d\-]{64,}\.)+?)[\w\d\.\-]+?(?<![\w\d\-\.]*?\.[\d]+?)(?<=[\w\d\-]{2,})(?<![\w\d\-]{25})$`

Proof, explanation and examples: https://regex101.com/r/FLA9Bv/9 (*Note: currently only works in Chrome because the regex uses lookbehinds which are only supported in ECMA2018*)

There're two approaches to choose from when validating domains.

By-the-books FQDN matching (theoretical definition, rarely encountered in practice):

- max 253 character long (as per [RFC-1035/3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), [RFC-2181/11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-11))
- max 63 character long per label (as per [RFC-1035/3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), [RFC-2181/11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-11))
- any characters are allowed (as per [RFC-2181/11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-11))
- TLDs cannot be all-numeric (as per [RFC-3696/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-2))
- FQDNs can be written in a complete form, which includes the root zone (the trailing dot)

Practical / conservative FQDN matching (practical definition, expected and supported in practice):

- by-the-books matching with the following exceptions/additions
- valid characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`
- labels cannot start or end with hyphens (as per [RFC-952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) and [RFC-1123/2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#section-2.1))
- TLD min length is 2 character, max length is 24 character as per currently existing records
- don't match trailing dot

Comment: It's wonderful, although it should not validate `a.b-.cc.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. Can't promise to look into it now but happy to take suggestions.

Comment: This regex will make your app crash in safari

Comment: Good job! I made a variant for coma separated domains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057243/regexp-to-match-comma-separated-hostnames/73896662#73896662

Answer (score 9):

```
^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,7}$
```

[domain - lower case letters and 0-9 only] [can have a hyphen] + [TLD - lower case only, must be beween 2 and 7 letters long]

http://rubular.com/ is brilliant for testing regular expressions!

Edit: Updated TLD maximum to 7 characters for '.rentals' as Dan Caddigan pointed out.

Comment: Why limit TLDs? Now `.photography` would be invalid. Just make it unlimited chars or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for pointing right direction in domain name validation solutions in other answers. Domain names could be validated in various ways.

If you need to validate **IDN** domain in it's **human readable** form, regex `\p{L}` will help. This allows to match any character in any language.

Note that **last part might contain hyphens** too! As punycode encoded Chineese names might have unicode characters in tld.

I've came to solution which will match for example:

- google.com
- masełkowski.pl
- maselkowski.pl
- m.maselkowski.pl
- www.masełkowski.pl.com
- xn--masekowski-d0b.pl
- 中国互联网络信息中心.中国
- xn--fiqa61au8b7zsevnm8ak20mc4a87e.xn--fiqs8s

Regex is:

```
^[0-9\p{L}][0-9\p{L}-\.]{1,61}[0-9\p{L}]\.[0-9\p{L}][\p{L}-]*[0-9\p{L}]+$
```

[Check and tune here](https://regex101.com/r/vX8vH8/26)

NOTE: This regexp is quite permissive, as is current domain names allowed character set.

**UPDATE**: Even more simplified, as `a-aA-Z\p{L}` is same as just `\p{L}`

NOTE2: The only problem is that it will match domains with double dots in it... , like `masełk..owski.pl`. If anyone know how to fix this please improve.

Comment: We can just use `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit]` instead of `\p{L}`. It works fine.

Comment: You can't validate an IDN this way without first converting it to punycode. For example with your expr, `中国互联网络信息中心中国互联网络信息中心中国互联网络信.中国` checks as valid, but after IDN conversion, it's too many bytes per label. \p{L} matches symbols, not punycode bytes (which vary from symbol to symbol), so repeat count is unhelpful when trying to limit its post-conversion size.

Comment: Good point, each part is limited to 64 bytes. However we can't check it with RegExp, so further validation steps are required using punycode decoder - which will fail with your example hostname. The chineese must be mad by this limitation.

Answer (score 5):

Not enough rep yet to comment. In response to paka's solution, I found I needed to adjust three items:

- The dash and underscore were moved due to the dash being interpreted as a range (as in "0-9")
- Added a full stop for domain names with many subdomains
- Extended the potential length for the TLDs to 13

Before:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

After:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][-_\.a-zA-Z0-9]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,13}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

Answer (score 3):

For new gTLDs

```
/^((?!-)[\p{L}\p{N}-]+(?<!-)\.)+[\p{L}\p{N}]{2,}$/iu
```

Comment: Please give us some more details what you answer make better than the others? What do you match more?Please edit your post directly to add the information.

Comment: Like i wrote: new gTLDs. Domains with unicode chars and also unicode TLDs.

Comment: @BenKeil: What is this part about: (?<!-)

Comment: @jor that is negative look behind.
Check this out https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/regex/cheatsheet

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Comment: -1 for the addition of {2,4}. It's possible to have single character TLDs (however, there are not currently any in the root). What about .mobile? .associates? Both are valid TLDs, and would be rejected by this regex. http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 2):

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9].[a-z]{2,3}(.[a-z]{2,3})?(.[a-z]{2,3})?$

Examples that work:

```
stack.com
sta-ck.com
sta---ck.com
9sta--ck.com
sta--ck9.com
stack99.com
99stack.com
sta99ck.com
```

It will also work for extensions

```
.com.uk
.co.in
.uk.edu.in
```

Examples that will not work:

```
-stack.com
```

it will work even with the longest domain extension `".versicherung"`

Answer (score 2):

```
^((localhost)|((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,253})$
```

Thank you @mkyong for the basis for my answer. I've modified it to support longer acceptable labels.

Also, "localhost" is technically a valid domain name. I will modify this answer to accommodate internationalized domain names.

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete code with example:

```
<?php
function is_domain($url)
{
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    if (isset($parse['host'])) {
        $domain = $parse['host'];
    } else {
        $domain = $url;
    }

    return preg_match('/^(?!\-)(?:[a-zA-Z\d\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,126}(?!\d+)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,63}$/', $domain);
}

echo is_domain('example.com'); //true
echo is_domain('https://example.com'); //true
echo is_domain('https://.example.com'); //false
echo is_domain('https://localhost'); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, quite permissive. It will have false positives like *-notvalid.at-all*, but it won't have false negatives.

```
/^([0-9a-z-]+\.?)+$/i
```

It makes sure it has a sequence of letters numbers and dashes that could end with a dot, and following it, any number of those kind of sequences.

The things I like about this regexp: it's short (maybe the shortest here), easily understandable, and good enough for validating user input errors in the client side.

Comment: I like this @pykiss. Simplicity in Regexes is important for maintainability. I think you can simplify this further by using `\w` as any word character like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which will include underscores, which is good. So it can become simply: `^([\w-]+\.?)+$`

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((([a-zA-Z]{1,2})|([0-9]{1,2})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/
```

- `([a-zA-Z]{1,2})` -> for accepting only two characters.
- `([0-9]{1,2})`-> for accepting two numbers only

if anything exceeds beyond two `([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])` this regex will take care of that.

If we want to do the matching for at least one time `+` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

- `^((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,}\.?((xn--)?([a-z0-9\-.]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{0,30})\.[a-z-1-9]{2,})$`

will validate such domains as `яндекс.рф` after encoding.

https://regex101.com/r/Hf8wFM/1 - sandbox

Comment: It's really good solutions, but the only problem with that it's supports domain over 63 characters, despite `{0,61}`. You know why?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex extracts the sub, root and tld of a given domain:

```
^(?<domain>(?<domain_sub>(?:[^\/\"\]:\.\s\|\-][^\/\"\]:\.\s\|]*?\.)*?)(?<domain_root>[^\/\"\]:\s\.\|\n]+\.(?<domain_tld>(?:xn--)?[\w-]{2,7}(?:\.[a-zA-Z-]{2,3})*)))$
```

Tested for the following domains:

```
* stack.com
* sta-ck.com
* sta---ck.com
* 9sta--ck.com
* sta--ck9.com
* stack99.com
* 99stack.com
* sta99ck.com
* google.com.uk
* google.co.in

* google.com
* masełkowski.pl
* maselkowski.pl
* m.maselkowski.pl
* www.masełkowski.pl.com
* xn--masekowski-d0b.pl
* xn--fiqa61au8b7zsevnm8ak20mc4a87e.xn--fiqs8s

* xn--stackoverflow.com
* stackoverflow.xn--com
* stackoverflow.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the below to simple fetch the domain along with the protocol.
Example:
https://www.facebook.com/profile/user/
ftp://182.282.34.337/movies/M

use the below Regex pattern :
[a-zA-Z0-9]+://.*?/

will get you the output :
https://www.facebook.com/
ftp://192.282.34.337/

Answer (score -1):

For Javascript you can have a look into the validator library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Method: `isFQDN(str [, options])`