# php preg_match validate domain

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to validate a domain .The expression must only be in the format .

```
   anywordwithoutspace.any
```

Here's my **code**

```
<?php
function validatereg($str1) {
    //validate domain
    if(preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])*(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', $str1) {
        //valid domain
    }
    else {
        //not a valid domain
    }
}
?>
```

I am not sure if its correct. Also please take note that after the period(which was 'any') can be any letter of maximum 4 letters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Domain name validation with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 if (preg_match("!"#$%&\'()*+,-./@:;<=>[\\]^_`{|}~", $myString)) 
    {
       //valid url
    }
```

This should do...

Comment: nice, i was only looking for a simple domain validator.

Comment: give it few more seconds until im able to do that

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with [FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php):

```
if (filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo "Domain is valid\n";
}
```

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN is better

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)([\.]{1})([A-Za-z0-9]+)([\.]{0,1})([A-Za-z0- 
   9]*)$/i", $domain)){
   $errors[] = "Domain is invalid";
}
```

This will validate most domains. I am using it on my website and it works pretty pretty good :)

Comment: Code-only answers tend to get deleted on StackOverflow. Try to add an explanation to your solution and how it differs from the other answers.

Comment: Your regex is wrong, it matches `---.abc.` that is not a valid domain name; moreover, it doesn't match `this.is.my.domain.name` that is valid.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
function is_valid_domain_name($domain_name)
{
    return (preg_match("/^([a-z\d](-*[a-z\d])*)(\.([a-z\d](-*[a-z\d])*))*$/i", $domain_name) //valid chars check
            && preg_match("/^.{1,253}$/", $domain_name) //overall length check
            && preg_match("/^[^\.]{1,63}(\.[^\.]{1,63})*$/", $domain_name)   ); //length of each label
}
?>
```

Comment: this one accepts local domains (like "localhost") It will even accept a phone number "123-332-123" and it will reject but valid UTF 8 domains.  Also you "borrowed" it from another answer.