# grep or sed pattern matching of domain name and truncating of subdomain?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am trying to extract a list of domain names from a httrack data stream using grep.  I have it close to working, but the result also includes any and all sub-domains.

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo "([0-9,a-z\.-]+)\.(com)"
```

Here is my current example result:

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- www.domain3.com
- subdomain.domain4.com
- whatever.domain5.com

Here is my desired example result.

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com
- domain4.com
- domain5.com

Is there something I can add to this grep expression, or should I pipe it to a new sed expression to truncate any subdomains?  And if so, how do I accomplish this task?  I'm stuck.  Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Wyatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop the `.` in the `grep` pattern. The following should work

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | 
grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to do a `.com` then the following will work as it will remove `HTTP://` with or without an s, and the next sub-domains. As you can see though it will only work for a .com.

```
/(?:https?:\/\/[a-z09.]*?)([a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.com)/
```

**Example Dataset**

```
http://www.ilovefreestuff.com/
https://test.ilovefreestuff.com/
https://test.sub.ilovefreestuff.com/
```

**[REGEX101](http://regex101.com/r/hR3aH4)**

That being said it is generally bad practice to parse and/or validate domain names using `Regex` as there are a ton of variants that can never be fully accounted for with the exception being when the conditions for matching and/or the dataset is clearly defined and not all encompassing. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex) post has more details on this process and covers a few more situations.

Answer (score 0):

**I use this code**

include all domain & subdomains

```
grep -oE '[[:alnum:]_.-]+[.][[:alnum:]_.-]+' file_name | sed -re 's/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}//g' | sort -u > test.txt
```