# How to iterate every string possible from a given pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

This is the a regular expression that validates the hostname of a url, taken from [Domain name validation with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex).

How can we iterate or create and loop through, every possible combination?
After each iteration of correct match a test will be done on the result.

Comment: Please show your work so far, and explain where you are stuck on this problem. You may also want to consider the scale of it - the number of possible valid URLs is very large, and any attempt to loop through them will not get very far into the set of all possibilities, or touch a meaningful fraction of real hostnames.

Comment: [HOP](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/06InfiniteStreams.pdf#18) covers this topic quite well. 
Just keep in mind you're looking at an absolutely enormous number of possibilities--that second character class on its own will match something in the area of 6.3x10^19 strings.

Comment: @Slade The second character class will actually match `2.2e+109` possible strings.  Add the fact that the last character class is unbounded, and this is definitely an odd goal.

Comment: What's a few dozen orders of magnitude between friends?

Comment: Re "This is the a regular expression that validates the hostname of a url", No it doesn't. It doesn't match `www.stackoverflow.com`, for example.

Comment: @ikegami, looking for the `hostname` part only

Comment: @Stevie G, And it fails to match the hostname `www.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @ikegami, don't want to get into a whole thing here but there is clearly some confusion regarding what that part of a url should be called and I've googled and it is not clear. If I can point to: http://rhwwebsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/domains_map_english.jpg, it would be the `name` part which as I explained is the `hostname`

Comment: Sounds like you want the company's top-level domain, but it fails at that too. e.g. The BBC's is `bbc.co.uk`.

Comment: @ikegami incorrect, I just want the `bbc` and it succeeds at that. I would prefer not to harp on this minor confusion you are having.

Comment: Well, it doesn't match `bbc` either.

Answer (score 1):

This will find 10<sup>116</sup> possibilities. That should be keep you going for a while, considering the planet only came into existence 10<sup>17</sup> seconds ago (almost yesterday!)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @char_set1 = ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9' );
my @char_set2 = ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9', '-');
my @char_set3 = (undef, 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9', '-');
my @char_set4 = ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z');
my @char_set5 = (undef, 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z');

my $iter = NestedLoops([
   (\@char_set4) x 2,
    ['.'],
   (\@char_set3) x 60,
    \@char_set2,
    \@char_set1,
]);

while (my @chars = $iter->()) {
   say join '', reverse grep defined, @chars;
}
```

This is not a general approach, just one that works well in this situation.

Comment: Also, there are only 10^80 atoms in the observable galaxy.

Comment: I reversed the order of the sets then reversed the output to produce a more natural order. It would go faster if you didn't this, but you seem to have lots of time.