# RegExp to match comma separated hostnames

Tags: javascript, regex

#### The problem

I'm trying to validate the content of a `<textarea>` using JavaScript, So I created a `validate()` function, which returns `true` or `false` wheter the text inside the textarea is valid or not.

The textarea can only contain **comma separated hostnames**. By hostname I mean something like `subdomain.domain.com`, so it's basically some dot separated strings. Since that users don't tend to write very well, I also want to allow the possibility of leaving any amount of spaces between the various hostnames and commas, **but not inside a hostname**.

Here are some examples of what should or shouldn't match:

- Should match:

  - `domain.com,domain2.co.vu,sub.domain.org`
  - `​    domai2n.com    ,    dom-ain.org.co.vu.nl   ,domain.it   ​`
  - `dom-ain.it, domain.com, domain.eu.org.something`
  - `a.b.c, a.b, a.a.a  , a.r`
  - `0191481.com`
- Should not match:

  - `domain.com., sub.domain.it` uncomplete hostname
  - `domain.me,   domain2` uncomplete hostname
  - `sub.sub.sub.domain.tv, do main.it` hostname contains spaces
  - `site` uncomplete hostname
  - `hèy.com` hostname cannot contain accents
  - `hey.01com` hostname cannot end with numbers or strings containing numbers
  - `hello.org..wow` uncomplete hostname

#### What I have tried so far

I built my function using the following code:

```
function validate(text) {
    return (
        (/^([a-z0-9\-\.]+ *, *)*[a-z0-9\-\.]+[^, ]$/i.test(text) 
        && !/\.[^a-z]|\.$/i.test(text)
        && ~text.indexOf('.'))
    );
}
```

unfortunately, my function just doesn't work. It fails to recognize uncomplete hostnames and returns `true`.

**Is there any method to accomplish this?** Maybe without using RegExps, even if I'd prefer to use a single RegExp.

Comment: So split, trim, and run a match.

Comment: Why not parse every whitespace back to a single white space, then split on `\s,` and evaluate every entry? Or use a domain reg ex to filter out only the good ones.

Comment: @Mouser how could I accomplish this?

Comment: something like `text.trim().split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean).every(/./.test, /^([a-z0-9\-\.]+ *, *)*[a-z0-9\-\.]+[^, ]$/ );` might need better regexp...

Comment: @epascarello can you please provide me an example/working snippet? I cannot figure that out.

Comment: @dandavis could you please make this into an answer (if it works) and explain it?

Comment: make an array of the terms between spaces, filter out empty ones, and return true if each one matches the regexp. i just used your regexp, which you said doesn't work. the regexp here need only match one valid domain at a time, which makes it simpler. i'm sure you can find/craft a suitable rx for the pattern...

Comment: [`validator.js`](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/) has `isFQDN`. so just `splt` and `trim` and test each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers saying to not use regex are perfectly fine, but I like regex so:

```
^\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-+\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-+\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*)*$
```

Yeah..it's not so pretty. But it works - tested on your sample cases at http://regex101.com

Edit: OK let's break it down. And only allow `sub-domain-01.com` and `a--b.com` and not `-.com`

Each subdomain thingo: `\w+(?:-+\w+)*` matches string of word characters plus optionally some words with dashes preceeding it.

Each hostname: `\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*` a bunch of subdomain thingos followed by a dot. Then finally followed by a string of letters only (the tld). And of course the optional spaces around the sides.

Whole thing: `\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*)*` a single hostname, followed by 0 or more `,hostname`s for our comma separated list.

Pretty simple really.

Comment: It looks like it's working... I don't wanna even know the sorcery behind this thing... but you got it!

Comment: Only one thing: "domain.-.com" matches, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli added some explanation and tried to fix the `domain.-.com` matching issue. You can tweak that bit of the regex to fit what kinds of hostnames you need to match.

Comment: "a----b.com" should match! It's a valid domain name, I've seen a bunch of these.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli updated :L

Can you have things like a--? or -a? Either way, you seem confident enough with regex to be able to tweak that part (subdomain thingo) to match what you need.

Comment: Actually you could have something like that, but it's an extreme case, I'd rater not allow those domains.

Answer (score 1):

While @dandavis's answer/comment is impressive, lets break it down in to steps.

1. Get the value from the textarea and `trim()` leading and ending spaces.
2. Replace all white spaces with a single white space using `/\s+/g`. meaning find every white space occurring one or more times.
3. Split by `,<space>` or `<space>,<space>`. Split returns array.
4. Iterate every array element with filter
5. Check if element is a valid domain. If so return it.

```js
var domains = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
domains = domains.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(/\s?,\s/);

var domainsTested = domains.filter(function(element){
                  if (element.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}\.([a-zA-Z]{1,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/))
                    {
                      return element;
                    }
              })

document.write(domainsTested.join(" | ")); //this is just here to show the results.
document.write("<br />Domainstring is ok: " + (domainsTested.length == domains.length)); //If it's valid then this should be equal.
```

```html
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px">www.example.com    , example.com, example.ca,     example, example.com example.nl     www.example,    www.exam ple.com,  sub.sub.sub.domain.tv, do main.it,   sub.domain.tv</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't want to test each hostname, I want to test the entire string and see if it's valid or not.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: then you should check the length of the filtered array. that's hard as-coded above because the array is re-defined. bottom line: you need to validate them individually to easily tell if all of them are valid; otherwise, you just make it hard on yourself. it not like it takes a long time to check them in a loop as opposed to all at once...

Comment: @dandavis took the code out of my mouth. Implemented a simple check here. You could also just for loop the domains array and when it finds a broken domain, break the loop and `return false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate() {
    //Get the user input
    var hostnames = document.getElementById('yourtextarea').value;
    //Regex to validate hostname
    var re = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/);
    //Trim whitespace
    hostnames = hostnames.trim();
    //Explode into an array
    hostnames = hostnames.split(",");
    //Loop through array & test each hostname with regex
    var is_valid = true;
    for (var i=0; i < hostnames.length; i++){
        var hostname = hostnames[i].trim();
        if (re.test(hostname)) {
           is_valid = true; //if valid, continue loop
        } else {
           is_valid = false; //if invalid, break loop and return false
           break;
        }
    } //end for loop
    return is_valid;
} //end function validate()
```

Matches every example you indicated except "dom-ain.it, domain.com, domain.eu.org.something" because "something" is not valid.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nesutqjf/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regexps for this, because you have a **lot** of different rules you want to check. Regexps are good when you only have a couple of rules that are very simple to express but a pain to write out as "parsing code".

I'd simply do `hostnames.split(',').forEach(validateHostname);`, as most of the comments suggest, and inside `validateHostname` reject any hostname that has spaces in the middle, two adjacent dots, no dots, ends in a dot, has non-ASCII characters, has digits in the last dot-separated token, and so on and so forth.

A function like this will be much easier to add new rules to than a regexp would be.

Comment: it sounds like you might be approaching the regexp backwards, which i agree is complicated. if we instead match just what we do want, instead of what we don't, then it's actually much simpler code in RegExp or via multiple IFs.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this pattern for awhile, and seems to be working for your case, too:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)+$/gi
```

The logic is simple:

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9]`: The URL must start with an alphanumeric character
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*`: The first alphanumeric character can be followed by zero or more of: an alphanumeric character, an underscore or a dash
- `\.`: The first piece must be followed by a period.
- The second piece must follow the same pattern:

  1. `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`: One or more alphanumeric character, OR
  2. `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+`: One or more alphanumeric character, an underscore or a dash followed by a period and one or more alphanumeric character

You can check this pattern working for most of your URLs in the following code snippet. How I do it is similar to the strategy described by others:

- Get the value of the textarea on keyup (or you can bind the submit, blur, keypress, keydown, change and etc)
- Split the value by the `,` character
- Use `$.trim()` to remove flanking whitespaces
- Use the RegEx pattern above to evaluate each individual string

Optional, done for visual output:

- Generate a list of URLs
- Indicate if each URL entered is valid or not

```js
$(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var urls = $(this).val().split(',');
        $('ul').empty();
        $.each(urls, function(i,v) {
            // Trim URL
            var url = $.trim(v);
            
            // RegEx
            var pat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)+$/gi,
                test = pat.test(url);
            
            // Append
            $('ul').append('<li>'+url+' <span>'+test+'</span></li>');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
ul span {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: .25em;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Paste URLs here"></textarea>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Why would you reject valid hostnames?

Comment: @Mouser OP said he wants to invalidate hostnames with underscore characters. **Edit:** What, OP just deleted his comment.

Comment: @Terry sorry, I just realized that hostnames can contain underscores, I thought they couldn't.

Comment: @Terry the question wasn't directed at you :-)

Answer (score 0):

An example with [`validate.js`](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/) which has well tested routines for testing a valid FQDN. Alternatively look through the source and grab what you need.

```js
function validate (e) {
    var target = e.target || e;
    
    target.value.split(',').some(function (item) {
        var notValid = !validator.isFQDN(item.trim());
        
        if (notValid) {
            target.classList.add('bad');
        } else {
            target.classList.remove('bad');
        }
      
      return notValid;
    });
}

var domains = document.getElementById('domains');

domains.addEventListener('change', validate);

validate(domains);
```

```css
#domains {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
.bad {
    background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="http://rawgit.com/chriso/validator.js/master/validator.js"></script>
<textarea id="domains">www.example.com, example.com, example.ca, example, example.com example.nl www.example, www.exam ple.com</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match every requirements for domains. It limits TLD to 24 characters becouse it's currently the longest TLD but u can change it to theoretical 63 chars (then u must change "25" to "64" - keep in mind that there are two instances of it):

```
^\s*(?!.*?_.*?)(?!(?:[\d\w]+?\.)?\-[\w\d\.\-]*?)(?![\w\d]+?\-\.(?:[\d\w\.\-]+?))(?=[\w\d])(?=[\w\d\.\-]*?\.+[\w\d\.\-]*?)(?![\w\d\.\-]{254})(?!(?:\.?[\w\d\-\.]*?[\w\d\-]{64,}\.)+?)[\w\d\.\-]+?(?<![\w\d\-\.]*?\.[\d]+?)(?<=[\w\d\-]{2,})(?<![\w\d\-]{25})(\s*,\s*(?!.*?_.*?)(?!(?:[\d\w]+?\.)?\-[\w\d\.\-]*?)(?![\w\d]+?\-\.(?:[\d\w\.\-]+?))(?=[\w\d])(?=[\w\d\.\-]*?\.+[\w\d\.\-]*?)(?![\w\d\.\-]{254})(?!(?:\.?[\w\d\-\.]*?[\w\d\-]{64,}\.)+?)[\w\d\.\-]+?(?<![\w\d\-\.]*?\.[\d]+?)(?<=[\w\d\-]{2,})(?<![\w\d\-]{25}))*\s*$
```

Here u can test it:
https://regex101.com/r/ZyPMn4/1