# Domain Name Regex Including IDN Characters c#

Tags: c#, regex, web, idn

I want my domain name to not contain more than one consecutive `(.)`, `'/'` or any other special characters. But it can contain IDN Characters such as `Á, ś, etc..`. I can achieve all requirements (except IDN) by using this regex:

```
@"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$";
```

Problem is that this regex denies IDN charaters too. I want a regex which will allow IDN characters. I did a lof of research but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Depending on the range of input values you expect, it might be worth using a transliteration library such as https://github.com/thecoderok/Unidecode.NET. Covering every character supported by IDN would lead to an awful regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brief

Regex contains a character class that allows you to specify Unicode general categories `\p{}`. The [MSDN regex documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character_classes) contains the following:

> `\p{ name }` Matches any single character in the Unicode general
>   category or named block specified by name.

Also, as a sidenote, I noticed your regex contains an unescaped `.`. In regex the dot character `.` has a special meaning of *any character (except newline unless otherwise specified)*. You may need to change this to `\.` to ensure proper functionality.

---

### Code

Editing your existing code to include Unicode character classes instead of simply the ASCII letters, you should attain the following:

```
^(?:[\p{L}\p{N}][\p{L}\p{N}-_]*.)+[\p{L}\p{N}]{2,}$
```

---

### Explanation

- `\p{L}` Represents the Unicode character class for any letter in any language/script
- `\p{N}` Represents the Unicode character class for any number in any language/script (based on your character samples, you can probably keep `0-9`, but I figured I would show you the general concept and give you slightly additional information)

[This site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) gives a quick and general overview of the most used Unicode categories.

> - `\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}`: any kind of letter from any language.
>
>   - `\p{Ll}` or `\p{Lowercase_Letter}`: a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.
>   - `\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}`: an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.
>   - `\p{Lt}` or `\p{Titlecase_Letter}`: a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is
>       capitalized.
>   - `\p{L&}` or `\p{Cased_Letter}`: a letter that exists in lowercase and uppercase variants (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt).
>   - `\p{Lm}` or `\p{Modifier_Letter}`: a special character that is used like a letter.
>   - `\p{Lo}` or `\p{Other_Letter}`: a letter or ideograph that does not have lowercase and uppercase variants.
> - `\p{M}` or `\p{Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).
>
>   - `\p{Mn}` or `\p{Non_Spacing_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character without taking up extra space (e.g.
>       accents, umlauts, etc.).
>   - `\p{Mc}` or `\p{Spacing_Combining_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character that takes up extra space (vowel
>       signs in many Eastern languages).
>   - `\p{Me}` or `\p{Enclosing_Mark}`: a character that encloses the character is is combined with (circle, square, keycap, etc.).
> - `\p{Z}` or `\p{Separator}`: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.
>
>   - `\p{Zs}` or `\p{Space_Separator}`: a whitespace character that is invisible, but does take up space.
>   - `\p{Zl}` or `\p{Line_Separator}`: line separator character U+2028.
>   - `\p{Zp}` or `\p{Paragraph_Separator}`: paragraph separator character U+2029.
> - `\p{S}` or `\p{Symbol}`: math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc.
>
>   - `\p{Sm}` or `\p{Math_Symbol}`: any mathematical symbol.
>   - `\p{Sc}` or `\p{Currency_Symbol}`: any currency sign.
>   - `\p{Sk}` or `\p{Modifier_Symbol}`: a combining character (mark) as a full character on its own.
>   - `\p{So}` or `\p{Other_Symbol}`: various symbols that are not math symbols, currency signs, or combining characters.
> - `\p{N}` or `\p{Number}`: any kind of numeric character in any script.
>
>   - `\p{Nd}` or `\p{Decimal_Digit_Number}`: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.
>   - `\p{Nl}` or `\p{Letter_Number}`: a number that looks like a letter, such as a Roman numeral.
>   - `\p{No}` or `\p{Other_Number}`: a superscript or subscript digit, or a number that is not a digit 0–9 (excluding numbers from
>       ideographic scripts).
> - `\p{P}` or `\p{Punctuation}`: any kind of punctuation character.
>
>   - `\p{Pd}` or `\p{Dash_Punctuation}`: any kind of hyphen or dash.
>   - `\p{Ps}` or `\p{Open_Punctuation}`: any kind of opening bracket.
>   - `\p{Pe}` or `\p{Close_Punctuation}`: any kind of closing bracket.
>   - `\p{Pi}` or `\p{Initial_Punctuation}`: any kind of opening quote.
>   - `\p{Pf}` or `\p{Final_Punctuation}`: any kind of closing quote.
>   - `\p{Pc}` or `\p{Connector_Punctuation}`: a punctuation character such as an underscore that connects words.
>   - `\p{Po}` or `\p{Other_Punctuation}`: any kind of punctuation character that is not a dash, bracket, quote or connector.
> - `\p{C}` or `\p{Other}`: invisible control characters and unused code points.
>
>   - `\p{Cc}` or `\p{Control}`: an ASCII or Latin-1 control character: 0x00–0x1F and 0x7F–0x9F.
>   - `\p{Cf}` or `\p{Format}`: invisible formatting indicator.
>   - `\p{Co}` or `\p{Private_Use}`: any code point reserved for private use.
>   - `\p{Cs}` or `\p{Surrogate}`: one half of a surrogate pair in UTF-16 encoding.
>   - `\p{Cn}` or `\p{Unassigned}`: any code point to which no character has been assigned.

Comment: Given all the information in the question, this does exactly what the OP is looking for, so why @wp78de is this not considered an accurate answer if it fixes the issues the OP was facing?

Comment: Anyway, it's not the most appropriate way to deal with IDNs using regex.

Comment: I agree, but the user was facing an issue with Unicode characters not being matched, so this solves the Unicode problem they were having.

Comment: This just reiterates your previous point and does not add any more substance :(

Comment: The above regex validates any word, even if not a domain: https://regex101.com/r/ke0WXc/2

Comment: it should be `\.` rather than `.` inside the regex

Comment: @devio this was answered for the initial revision that the user submitted. It’s likely that `.` should be escaped. I made mention of this in my answer. It’s also likely that `.` should be a character class of symbols (minus `-_`), so `[\P{S}_-]`

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered with a simple regex that allows all sorts of Unicode character classes since the [IDN Character Categorization](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/idn-chars.html) defines many illegal characters and there are other limitations.

AFAIK, IDN domain names start with xn--. This way extended UTF-8 characters are enabled in domain names, e.g. 大众汽车.cn is a valid domain name (volkswagen in Chinese). To validate this domain name using regex, you need to let http://xn--3oq18vl8pn36a.cn/ (the ACE equivalent of 大众汽车) pass.
In order to do so, you will need to encode domain names to [ASCII Compatible Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode) (ACE) using [GNU Libidn](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/) (or any other library that implements IDNA), [Doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/manual/libidn.html)/[PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/manual/libidn.pdf).

Libidn comes with a CLI tool called `idn` that allows you to convert a hostname in UTF-8 to ACE encoding. The resulting string can then be used as ACE-encoded equivalent of UTF-8 URL.

```
  $ idn --quiet -a 大众汽车.cn
  xn--3oq18vl8pn36a.cn
```

Inspired by [paka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046959/8291949) and [timgws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26987741/8291949) and I suggest the following regular expression, that should cover most domains:

`^(?!-)(xn--)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}\.(?!-)(xn--)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,50}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$`

Here are some samples:

```
#Valid
xn-fsqu00a.xn-0zwm56d
xn-fsqu00a.xn--vermgensberatung-pwb
xn--stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.xn--com
stackoverflow.co.uk
google.com.au
i.oh1.me
wow.british-library.uk
xn--stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.xn--com
stackoverflow.co.uk
0-0O_.COM
a.net
0-0O.COM
0-OZ.CO.uk
0-TENSION.COM.br
0-WH-AO14-0.COM-com.net
a-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234-z.eu.us
#Invalid
-0-0O.COM
0-0O.-COM
-a.dot
a-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-12345-z.eu.us
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dfEeDy/4)

Visualization

[image]

Some useful links

- [Top level domains - Delegated string](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings)
- [Internationalized Domain Names (IDN) FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/idn.html)
- [Internationalized Domain Names Support page from Oracle's International Language Environment Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmkx.html)

If you would like to use Unicode character classes \p{} instead, you should use  the following [as specified by the IDN FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/idn.html#33):

```
[ \P{Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded}
- \p{c} - \p{z}
- \p{s} - \p{p} - \p{nl} - \p{no} - \p{me}
- \p{HST=L} - \p{HST=V} - \p{HST=V}
- \p{block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks_For_Symbols}
- \p{block=Musical_Symbols}
- \p{block=Ancient_Greek_Musical_Notation}
- [\u0640 \u07FA \u302E \u302F \u3031-\u3035 \u303B]
+ [\u00B7 \u0375 \u05F3 \u05F4 \u30FB]
+ [\u002D \u06FD \u06FE \u0F0B \u3007]
+ [\u00DF \u03C2]
+ \p{JoinControl}]
```

See also: [Perl Unicode properties](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

"There are several reasons why one may need to validate a domain or an Internationalized Domain Name.

1. To accept only the functional domains which resolve when probed through a DNS query
2. To accept the strings which can potentially act (get registered and subsequently resolved, or only for the sake of information) as domain name

Depending on the nature of the need, the ways in which the domain name can be validated, differs a great deal.

For validating the domain names, only from pure technical specification point of view, regardless of it's resolvability vis-a-vis the DNS, is a slightly more complex problem than merely writing a Regex with certain number of Unicode classes.

There is a host of RFCs (5891,5892,5893,5894 and 5895) that together define, the structure of a valid domain ( IDN in specific, domain in general) name. It involves not only various Unicode Character classes, but also includes some context specific rules which need a full-fledged algorithm of their own. Typically, all the leading programming languages and frameworks provide a way to validate the domain names as per the latest IDNA Protocol i.e. IDNA 2008.

**C# provides a library: System.Globalization.IdnMapping** that provides conversion of a domain name to it's equivalent punycode version. You can use this library to check if the user submitted domain is compliant with the IDNA norms. If it is not, during the conversion you will encounter an error/exception, thereby validating the user submission.

If one is interested to dig deeper into the topic, please do refer the very thoroughly research document produced by the "Universal Acceptance Steering Group" (https://uasg.tech/), titled, "UASG 018A UA Compliance of Some Programming Language Libraries and Frameworks (https://uasg.tech/download/uasg-018a-ua-compliance-of-some-programming-language-libraries-and-frameworks-en/ as well as "UASG 037 UA-Readiness of Some Programming Language Libraries and Frameworks EN" (https://uasg.tech/download/uasg-037-ua-readiness-of-some-programming-language-libraries-and-frameworks-en/).

In addition, those who are interested to know the overall process, challenges and issues one may come across while implementing the Internationalized Email Solution, one can also go through the following RFCs: RFC 6530 (Overview and Framework for Internationalized Email), RFC 6531 (SMTP Extension for Internationalized Email), RFC 6532 (Internationalized Email Headers), RFC 6533 (Internationalized Delivery Status and Disposition Notifications), RFC 6855 (IMAP Support for UTF-8), RFC 6856 (Post Office Protocol Version 3 (POP3) Support for UTF-8), RFC 6857 (Post-Delivery Message Downgrading for Internationalized Email Messages), RFC 6858 (Simplified POP and IMAP Downgrading for Internationalized Email).)."