# Regex for finding domains in a sentence but not IP addresses

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match domains in a sentence.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/what-is-a-regular-expression-which-will-match-a-valid-domain-name-without-a-subd) which was very useful and helped me create the following to match domains, but it also unfortunately matches IP addresses too which I do not want:

```
((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,1}\.(xn--)?([a-z0-9\._-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30})
```

I want to update my expression so that the following can still be found: in a sentence, between brackets, etc.:

```
www.example.com
subdomain.example.com
subdomain.example.co.uk
```

But not:

```
192.168.0.0
127.0.0.1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may match IPs and match and capture everything else using your regex. Something like `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(your_regex)` and grab Group 1 values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the suggestion but that still selects IP addresses unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, but you do not have to *keep* them, as you only need to grab Group 1 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a simple lookahead that excludes combinations of numbers and dots only: `(?![\d.]+)`

```
(?![\d.]+)((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,1}\.(xn--)?([a-z0-9\._-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XewLMK/1)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @wp78de is correct, however it would not detect the domains starting with Numerical digits i.e. 123reg.com

So remove the first group in the regex like this

```
((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,1}\.(xn--)?([a-z0-9\._-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30})
```