# Validator for domain name in Angular?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I need to run validation on one of the form fields in my app. For this, I am using `ReactiveFormsModule`

My pattern as follows:

`domainPattern = '^(((?!-))(xn--|_{1,1})?[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn--)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$';`

I am using the above pattern in my pattern Validator code as follows:

```
this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
      name: [ '' ],
      company: [ '' ],
      email: [ '', [ Validators.required, Validators.email ] ],
      domain: [ '', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern( this.domainPattern ) ] ]
    } );
```

For `email` it's standard working well.
But for the custom domain regex doesn't work for me. I have used regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/what-is-a-regular-expression-which-will-match-a-valid-domain-name-without-a-subd/26987741#26987741).

Based on the questions reviewed it seems difficult to find general domain name regex for all of the valid domains but I want to cover most basic cases.

The current pattern shows: `$#$#.com`, `abcd` as valid domains.

Do Validators have any constant validator similar to `Validators.email` for the domain?

Comment: `abcd` is a valid domain (it doesn't exist, although `abc` does, but it is valid)

Comment: _Do Validators have any constant validator similar to Validators.email for the domain?_ No

Comment: You are missing literal backslashes in your regex, use `domainPattern = /^(((?!-))(xn--|_)?[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)*(xn--)?([a-z0-9-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$/`