# How to skip a certain group of characters (https://) in regexmatch google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to do some regex and am restricted to a google sheet where I don't have my sweet, sweet, python string methods.

**Preferred result:**

I am using `=REGEXMATCH()` in google sheets and want to parse URLs. For example, for the following url:

`https://www.foobar.com/foo/bar`

I'd like to get everything after `https://` and before the first `/` after the domain, like so (assume all my urls start with `https://` and have extensions after the base url.

`www.foobar.com`

---

**What I have tried:**

I have the following formula that gets me close:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^https?:\/\/[^\/]+")`

`https://foobar.com`

But I still need to get rid of the `https://`

I also tried a positive look behind assertion but to no avail:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"/ (?<=https?:\/\/)[^\/]/+")`

but I get an error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/what-is-a-regular-expression-which-will-match-a-valid-domain-name-without-a-subd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"https:\//(.*?)\/")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Using the parenthesis (), which means extract a group of characters inside. Then using the dot "." which means any characters except new line. Then you state the characters before and after the string you want to extract.

Refer to this link:
[REGEX Cheat Sheet](https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted something that wasn't using Regex (which based on your fondness of python is unlikely), you could use a more *spreadsheet-like* approach.

9 represents the length of `https//`. If you wanted to check for without the s you could include an if statement.

```
=mid(A1,9,find("/",mid(A1,9,len(A1)))-1)
```