# PowerShell: Replace underscores with either a period or @ sign

Tags: powershell, replace

In PowerShell, I'm looking to convert a SharePoint Location string (john_smith_domain_com) to the proper addressing of john.Smith@domain.com.
I'm not sure which is the best way to go about doing this.
I know `$var.Replace("_",".")` would work to replace all the "_"s with "."s, but that doesn't help the "@" going between the name and the domain.

Unfortunately, the domain isn't always the same, or I'd be able to just .replace it easily.

Comment: if the domain is always composed of the last 2 tokens you could deal with it with splitting

Comment: can the domains have more than 2 tokens? i.e.: `[mailaddress] 'john.smith@domain.xyz.foo'` would be a valid email address, if so, there is no programmatical way of telling which part is the host and which part is the user of your email address unless you have a list of all valid domains.

Comment: So, they're valid domains, we just have a bunch of them. My script will not know what domain will come through until it hits this section. So I could have john.smith@domain1.com, john.smith@domain2.com, etc. but never subdomains. My thought was take the second to last _ and make it an @ sign, and replace the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine two [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operations (this assumes a *two-component* domain name, such as `domain.com`):

```bash
# -> 'john.smith@domain.com'
'john_smith_domain_com' -replace '_(?![^_]+_[^_]+$)', '.' -replace '_', '@'
```

- [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `_(?![^_]+_[^_]+$)` matches all `_` chars. except the *second-to-last* one.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the ability to interact with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/Xa05Pf/1).
- After all these have been replaced with `.`, only the second-to-last one is left, which can then be replaced with `@`

---

As [JohnLBevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan) notes, if there are domain names with a *varying* number of components, you have two options:

- *If* you can assume that all users names are in the form `<firstName>.<lastName>` (as governed by a policy), you can replace the *second* `_` with `@`:

```bash
# -> 'john.smith@domain.co.uk'
'john_smith_domain_co_uk' -replace '^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_', '$1.$2@' -replace '_', '.'
```

- Otherwise, as John notes:

> You may want something that's aware of the more common TLDs / caters for more common domain formats. Some options are in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10306690/361842).

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick at least for my test user, so I expect it to work for the rest. I knew it was possible with regex, I just haven't been able to grasp the concept of it yet...

Comment: NB: It may make sense to assume that the format is always `firstname_lastname` (if that's governed somewhere; e.g. by company policy) rather than assuming `domain_tld` as the the latter may have issues with some tlds (top level domains), like `.co.uk`.  Here's one possible alternative for that approach: `'john_smith_domain_co_uk' -replace '_', '.' -replace '^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)\.', '$1@'`.  If you can't rely on `first.last` either, you may want something that's aware of the more common tlds / caters for more common domain formats.  Some optoins here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10306690/361842

Comment: Thanks, @JohnLBevan - good info; I've added it to the answer (I've tweaked the regex to be more similar the other solution in the answer; as an inconsequential aside: no need to escape a literal `.` as ``\.`` inside `[…]`).

Comment: Nice one; thanks @mklement0 ; good tip; I always forget where escapes aren't needed / have a bad habit of overescaping.