# javascript url split for manually entering url in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am manually entering a url link in a Html form  which might be

```
https://localhost/inc/Pega/Some.pdf or inc/Pega/Some.pdf ,
```

i need to check whether the url contains any link i.e https

1)  if it contains  then i have to strip text link to

```
'inc/Pega/Some.pdf'
```

Comment: Is link always start with `https://localhost` ?

Comment: It may differ ! it may starts with https://somelink or sometimes from inc/Docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the required part of url using substring

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9AYGu/)**

```
if(url.indexOf('https:') == 0)
   $('#text1').val(url.substring(url.indexOf('inc/Pega')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following JavaScript:

```
var url = "https://localhost/inc/Pega/Some.pdf";
url = url.replace(/^(http[s]*:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\//,"")
```

Now explanation: From the begging of string (^) I remove protocol (http or https) then everything between `://` and `/`, which is letters, numbers or underscore.
If link will not start with `http://` or `https://` or `/` nothing will be changed

Comment: Thanks for your code but when i check with /inc/Docs/Some.pdf it returns the same! it should return inc/Docs/Some.pdf! can u alter ur code

Comment: and one more thing when i put something https://something.domain.com/inc/Docs/soem.pdf it doesnt work

Comment: @Mazher about  something.domain.com/inc/Docs/soem.pdf  it will be always dots in server name? Or something.domain.com is static?

Comment: @Mazher mark it as answer or vote it up instead of writing: thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given a variable `link`,

```
var link = link.replace("https://localhost/", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var newurl = url.replace("https://localhost/", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

please look into following links ,you may get some idea,

[How do you strip out the domain name from a URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176284/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php)

[regex needed to strip out domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791700/regex-needed-to-strip-out-domain-name)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190207/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php-trying-again

http://snipplr.com/view/12737/

hope these will help

Answer (score 0):

Run this JS function while submitting the form :

```
function check_URL_Is_Valid(url){
  var regular_exp = new RegExp("^(http|https)://", "i");
  var given_url = url;
  var match = regular_exp.test(given_url);
  if (match){
    alert('URL is valid');
    var sub_url = given_url.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([a-zA-Z-_]+).*$/)[0];
    alert('SubURL='+sub_url);
  }else{
    alert('URL is Invalid');
  }
}
```

I hope this will fulfill your requirement. Please let me know if you face any problem.